# UISearchBar same as like iMac Finder Search Functionality

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I met with an requirement in which I had UISearchBar as like follows.

**Step : 1 (Initial look of the SearchBar)**

[image]

**Step : 2 (User types string and immediate Search)**

[image]

**Step : 3 (Selecting any of them in the Search List)**

[image]

**Step : 4 (Adding the button on the SearchBar)**

[image]

**Step : 5 (Finally Action on the Button)**

[image]

This might continue. I mean to say is he can enter the text further more but the functionality should be the same.

Could anyone please help me ? Please, I am in a need.

**UPDATE**

You can watch this same functionality on your iMac Finder Search

**This is what i have tried.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "customPopOverController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *searchView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITableView *sampleView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayForListing;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *txtFieldSearch;
@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize searchView = _searchView;
@synthesize customPopOverController = _customPopOverController;
@synthesize txtFieldSearch = _txtFieldSearch;
@synthesize sampleView = _sampleView;
@synthesize arrayForListing = _arrayForListing;
@synthesize btnforExtra = _btnforExtra;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.arrayForListing = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self loadTheSearchView];
    [self applyUIStyle];
}
- (void)loadTheSearchView
{
    self.searchView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 44)];
    [self.searchView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchView];
    [self placeTheTextView];
}
- (void)placeTheTextView
{
    self.txtFieldSearch = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 9, 230, 30)];
    [self.txtFieldSearch setDelegate:self];
    [self.searchView addSubview:self.txtFieldSearch];
}
- (void)applyUIStyle
{
    self.searchView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0f;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

}
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField.text.length!=0)
    {
        [self.arrayForListing removeAllObjects];
        [self.arrayForListing addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"File Contains %@",textField.text]];

        [self callThePop];
    }
    return YES;
}
- (void)callThePop
{
    UIViewController *contentViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(self.searchView.frame.size.width, 50);
    self.sampleView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover.width, contentViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover.height)];
    [self.sampleView setDelegate:self];
    [self.sampleView setDataSource:self];
    [self.sampleView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched];
    [self.sampleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [contentViewController.view addSubview:self.sampleView];

    self.customPopOverController = [[customPopOverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:contentViewController];
    self.customPopOverController.delegate = self;

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(callYourMethod:)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.sampleView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];

    [self.customPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.searchView.frame inView:self.view  permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp|UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown| UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft|UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight) animated:YES];
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
#pragma mark - Table View Delegate Methods
#pragma mark
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.arrayForListing.count;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifer = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifer];
    }
    cell.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [cell.textLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.arrayForListing objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS" size:14]];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (self.customPopOverController)
    {
        [self.customPopOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }
    UITableViewCell * cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (self.txtFieldSearch.text.length == 0)
    {
        self.txtFieldSearch.text = cell.textLabel.text;
    }
    else
    {
        self.btnforExtra = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10+(buttonsCount*45), 8, 45, 25)];
        [self.btnforExtra setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.503 green:0.641 blue:0.794 alpha:1.000]];
        [self.btnforExtra setTitle:self.txtFieldSearch.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnforExtra setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.btnforExtra.layer setCornerRadius:8.0f];
        [self.txtFieldSearch setFrame:CGRectMake(self.btnforExtra.frame.origin.x+self.btnforExtra.frame.size.width+10, 9, 230, 30)];
        self.txtFieldSearch.text = @"";
        [self.searchView addSubview:self.btnforExtra];
        buttonsCount++;
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView.editing == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [self.arrayForListing removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView endUpdates];
    }
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"IndexPath.row == %i", indexPath.row);
}
#pragma mark - custom PopOver Delegate Methods
#pragma mark
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(customPopOverController *)thePopoverController
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(customPopOverController *)thePopoverController
{
    self.customPopOverController = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: The way you explained your question is Awesome.....

Comment: It will look great if you can decrease your Font size.

Comment: As you don't seem to have a particular problem, here's a piece of advice: create separate classes like a button span with popover, another popover for the search field, etc. Will make easier to divide the problem into tasks and at some point they'll just all work together.

Comment: Exactly, create a custom `UIView` with search functionality and delegate methods. After that create custom `UIButton`s for the selected search tags.

Comment: Please call me manohar.

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: this solution is deeply flawed, probably in many ways. It's the first solution that I came up with and I've done VERY little optimization on it (aka none).

So, I was bored, and I came up with something that I think fits the bill. Keep in mind that this only does the display of what you're asking about (and it does it somewhat poorly at that), it does not handle the actual search functionality as I'm not sure what you're searching. It also has some static values programmed in (such as file types array, and I dropped the view controller into a `UINavigationController` and did some static sizes based on that) that you'll want to change. I make use of `WYPopoverController`, which can be found here: [WYPopoverController](https://github.com/nicolaschengdev/WYPopoverController). Let me know how it works for you- feel free to critique the hell out if it.

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WYPopoverController.h"
#import "SearchButton.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController () <WYPopoverControllerDelegate>
{
    UITextField *searchField;

    UIView *searchesView;
    UIScrollView *scrollView;
    WYPopoverController *newSearchController;
    WYPopoverController *existingSearchController;
    NSMutableArray *buttonsArray;
    SearchButton *activeButton;
    NSArray *kindsArray;
    NSMutableArray *matchedKinds;

    // using UITableViewController instead of just UITableView so I can set preferredContentSize on the controller
    UITableViewController *searchTable;
    UITableViewController *existingTable;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    searchField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 75, 280, 30)];
    searchField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    searchField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    searchField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:searchField];

    searchesView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, searchField.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, searchField.frame.size.height)];

    [scrollView addSubview:searchesView];

    searchField.leftView = scrollView;
    searchField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
    [searchField becomeFirstResponder];

    kindsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Audio", @"Video", @"Other", @"Text", nil];
    matchedKinds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    buttonsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [searchField addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Text Field Delegate

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [newSearchController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:newSearchController];
    }];

    return YES;
}

// not technically part of the TF delegate, but it fits better here
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)tf
{
    if(tf.text.length > 0)
    {
        if(newSearchController == nil)
        {
            searchTable = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
            searchTable.tableView.delegate = self;
            searchTable.tableView.dataSource = self;
            searchTable.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 136);

            newSearchController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:searchTable];
            newSearchController.delegate = self;
            newSearchController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
            newSearchController.theme.arrowHeight = 5;
            searchTable.tableView.tag = 1;

            [newSearchController presentPopoverFromRect:searchField.bounds
                                                 inView:searchField
                               permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                               animated:YES
                                                options:WYPopoverAnimationOptionFadeWithScale];
        }

        [matchedKinds removeAllObjects];
        for(NSString *type in kindsArray)
        {
            NSRange foundRange = [[type lowercaseString] rangeOfString:[tf.text lowercaseString]];
            if(foundRange.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                // Found a match!
                [matchedKinds addObject:type];
            }
        }

        [searchTable.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else
    {
        [newSearchController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:newSearchController];
        }];
    }
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if(tableView.tag == 1)
        return 2;

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        if(section == 0)
            return 1;

        return [matchedKinds count];
    }

    return 3;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        if(section == 0)
            return @"Filenames";
        else
            return @"Kinds";
    }

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 30.0f;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"reuser"];

    // Configure the cell...
    if(tableView.tag == 1)
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name matches: %@", searchField.text];

        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [matchedKinds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            switch (tableView.tag) {
                case 2:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Filename";
                    break;

                default:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Kind";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Everything";
        else
            cell.textLabel.text = @"<Delete>";

    }


    return cell;
}


#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(tableView.tag == 1)  // new search table tapped
    {
        SearchButton *searchedButton = [SearchButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];

        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            searchedButton.type = ButtonTypeName;
            searchedButton.searchedString = searchField.text;
        }
        else
        {
            searchedButton.type = ButtonTypeKind;
            searchedButton.searchedString = [matchedKinds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }

        searchedButton.defaulted = YES;
        searchedButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
        [searchedButton setTitleColor:[UIColor darkTextColor]
                             forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [searchedButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(buttonTapped:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [searchedButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:1.0f]];
        searchedButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
        searchedButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [buttonsArray addObject:searchedButton];
        activeButton = searchedButton;
        searchField.text = @"";

        [self updateButtonsFromCreation:YES];


        [newSearchController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:newSearchController];
        }];
    }
    else    // text field of an existing search
    {
        switch (indexPath.row) {
            case 0:
                activeButton.defaulted = YES;
                break;

            case 1:
                activeButton.defaulted = NO;
                break;

            default:
                [buttonsArray removeObject:activeButton];
                break;
        }

        [self updateButtonsFromCreation:NO];
        [existingSearchController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES completion:^{
            [self popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:existingSearchController];
        }];


    }
}


#pragma  mark - Popover delegate

- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(WYPopoverController *)controller
{
    if(controller == newSearchController)
    {
        newSearchController = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        existingSearchController = nil;
    }
}



#pragma mark - Other functions

- (void)updateButtonsFromCreation:(BOOL)creation
{
    [[searchesView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    float widthTotal = 0;
    for(SearchButton *button in buttonsArray)
    {
        NSString *buttonText;

        if(button.defaulted)
        {
            if(button.type == ButtonTypeName)
                buttonText = @"Name: ";
            else
                buttonText = @"Kind: ";
        }
        else
            buttonText = @"Any: ";

        buttonText = [buttonText stringByAppendingString:button.searchedString];

        [button setTitle:buttonText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        CGSize buttonSize = [buttonText sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f]}];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(widthTotal + 2, 2, buttonSize.width + 4, searchField.frame.size.height - 4);
        widthTotal += button.frame.size.width + 2;

        [searchesView addSubview:button];
    }

    searchesView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthTotal, searchesView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ((widthTotal > 200) ? 200 : widthTotal), scrollView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(widthTotal, scrollView.frame.size.height);

    if(creation)
    {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(activeButton.frame.origin.x, 0);
    }
}


- (void)buttonTapped:(SearchButton *)sender
{
    activeButton = sender;
    existingTable = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    existingTable.tableView.delegate = self;
    existingTable.tableView.dataSource = self;
    existingTable.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(160, 90);

    existingSearchController = [[WYPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:existingTable];
    existingSearchController.delegate = self;
    existingSearchController.popoverLayoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    existingSearchController.theme.arrowHeight = 5;
    existingTable.tableView.tag = sender.type;

    [existingSearchController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame
                                              inView:scrollView
                            permittedArrowDirections:WYPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                            animated:YES
                                             options:WYPopoverAnimationOptionFadeWithScale];
}


@end
```

**SearchButton.h**

```
typedef enum {ButtonTypeName = 2,
              ButtonTypeKind = 3} ButtonType;

@interface SearchButton : UIButton

@property (nonatomic) ButtonType type;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL defaulted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *searchedString;

@end
```

**SearchButton.m**

```
no changes to default generated
```